# Recursive Search in BST

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

```
TreeNode search(int value, TreeNode root)
{

    if(root.data==value)
    {
        return root;
    }
    else if(root.data < value)
    {
        search(value, root.Right);
    }
    else if (root.data > value)
    {
        search(value, root.Left);
    }

   return root;

}
```

I want to search a node in BST, the problem is that this function returns several times. It does return the correct Node but finally returns Null. Help me improve it.

Comment: Also check at the begining if root == null and return null. That way you won't get an error if there is no node which you are searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    search(value, root.Right);
```

to

```
    return search(value, root.Right);
```

(and also for `root.Left`).

Otherwise you are ignoring the return value of the recursive invocations.

Comment: So if i do root = search(value, root.Right); , Does it mean the same?

Comment: It's the same in this case.